# Are there combinations of hue-sat-brightness equal?

Tags: color, rgb, paint.net, palette, hsb

So I coded a customized palette-creation script but when copying palettes to paint.net and other pieces of software I notice something weird:

Occasionally when I create a colour it will slightly tweak the HSB. Say if I create (45, 80%, 94%) it changes it too (43, 80%, 92%). Is this because those HSB colours are equal? Why does this happen?

Thanks!

Comment: Illustrator also tends to this. Extremely annoying. Isn't this because the colors are stored as RGB or CMYK? I always assumed these deviations occurred from the conversion of hsl to RGB and back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are not equivalent:

[image]

The upper half is the first and the lower is the second.

I do not know, why your program does such changes. One possiblity is that you have activated some option that restricts your selectable color range to some predefined palette.

Comment: RGB to CMYK conversion?

Comment: I didn't activate any option like that, sadly =(. Thanks a lot for your help, they are indeed not equivalent =)